# Калькулятор на Android ,основные операции

Tags: java, android, калькулятор

Скиньте пожалуйста супер подробный урок на русском языке как сделать нормальный калькулятор как на всех смартфонах .Больше всего я не могу понять как реализовать математические операции.Мне бы понять хотя бы как основные действия прописать(+-*/=). Заранее благодарю.

Comment: нормальные калькуляторы работают по алгоритму [обратной польской нотации](https://yandex.ru/turbo?text=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25D0%259E%25D0%25B1%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D1%2582%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B0%25D1%258F_%25D0%25BF%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BB%25D1%258C%25D1%2581%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B0%25D1%258F_%25D0%25B7%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BF%25D0%25B8%25D1%2581%25D1%258C%3Futm_source%3Dturbo&fallback=1)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/georrge1994/1.calculation здесь я когда-то реализовывал алгоритм калькулятора в привычном представлении на java. Чтобы собрать просто калькулятор, Вам достаточно любознательности и гугла) урок здесь не нужен, это очень просто!